# How to add different pricing for Cash on delivery on Woocommerce?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

Hy, I added two payment methods, COD and card payment, and have two shipping methods, one for COD one for card, on Woocommerce COD setting I disabled shipping method being used for card payment, but my card settings dont have that option so I've used code to hide COD shipping when card paymeny is selected, but when I do that, I cant no longer change nor payment nor shipping methods.

```
    add_action( 'woocommerce_package_rates','show_hide_shipping_methods', 10, 2 );
function show_hide_shipping_methods( $rates, $package ) {
    $payment_method        = 'monri';
    $payment_method1        = 'bacs';
    $chosen_payment_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_payment_method');

    if( $payment_method == $chosen_payment_method || $payment_method1 == $chosen_payment_method ){
        unset($rates['flexible_shipping_single:10']);
    }
    return $rates;
}
```

All I want is to have both COD and card payment buttons on checkout, and when they are selected that corect shipping methods are selected

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it, not the cleanest way, but it works.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways', 'filter_payment_gateways_based_on_shipping', 10, 1);
    function filter_payment_gateways_based_on_shipping($available_gateways) {
        // Check if specific shipping method is selected
        if (is_checkout()) {
            $chosen_shipping_method = WC()->session->get('chosen_shipping_methods')[0];
            
            // List of shipping methods for which you want to disable payment methods
            $shipping_methods_to_check = array('flexible_shipping_single:4'); // Adjust with your shipping method IDs, you can get these in many way, easiest, inspect the checkbox on payment page
            
            // List of payment methods to be disabled
            $payment_methods_to_disable = array('cod'); // Adjust with your payment method IDs
            
            if (in_array($chosen_shipping_method, $shipping_methods_to_check)) {
                foreach ($payment_methods_to_disable as $method_id) {
                    if (isset($available_gateways[$method_id])) {
                        unset($available_gateways[$method_id]);
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // List of shipping methods for which you want to disable payment methods
            $shipping_methods_to_check = array('flexible_shipping_single:13'); // Adjust with your shipping method IDs, you can get these in many way, easiest, inspect the checkbox on payment page
            
            // List of payment methods to be disabled
            $payment_methods_to_disable = array('monri', 'bacs'); // Adjust with your payment method IDs
            
            if (in_array($chosen_shipping_method, $shipping_methods_to_check)) {
                foreach ($payment_methods_to_disable as $method_id) {
                    if (isset($available_gateways[$method_id])) {
                        unset($available_gateways[$method_id]);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return $available_gateways;
    }
```